# Determine the least number of comparisons, or best-case performance of the following algorithms

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine the least number of comparisons, or best-case performance,

1. required to find the maximum of a sequence of n integers.
2. used to locate an element in a list of n terms with a linear
   search.
3. used to locate an element in a list of n terms using a binary search.

The answer I found says that:

1. $n-1$ comparisons.
2. $1$ comparison
3. $\left\lceil \log(n) \right\rceil$ comparisons.

**Question:** But in best case, I guess all of them take $\mathcal{O}(1)$. I guess either the question is wrong or my interpretation is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, suppose the first element is in fact the maximum. Sure, you *see* it, but how can you be *sure* it is the maximum? You need to compare this element with the other $n-1$ elements to *prove* it is the maximum.

However, the best case for the third problem really should be one comparison under the implied assumption that the list is sorted; you determine a "middle" element and it happens to be *equal* to the search key, you're done.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you to remind me of implied assumption as I thought it's the case for all 3 questions.

Comment: Can you explain about linear search? It should also have $n-1$ similar to the first scenario please?